# How to store data that can be either a numeric range or a numeric value?

Tags: database, database-design, normalization, database-normalization

In my table I need to store a physical quantity that can be given either as a numeric value or as a numeric interval. The table below illustrates the idea:

```
------------------------------
Isotope_ID   |  Atomic_Weight   
------------------------------
     1       |    1.00784
     2       | [6.938, 6.997] 
    ...      |       ...
```

This table is unacceptable because the field Atomic_Weight contains values of different types. What is the best practice in such cases?

Edit1: There are three possible ways to represent information about atomic weight:

1. value + (uncertainty), e.g. 1.00784 (9)
2. interval, e.g. [6.938, 6.997]
3. mass number of the most stable isotope e.g 38

These three subtypes cannot be stored in one field because this would violate 1 Normalization Form. This is why the example table is unacceptable.
I will try to restate my question more clearly: What are possible ways to store information about atomic weight (that can be given in one of the three different subtypes) in my database?

Comment: 1. Please expand on what "these cases" means. Cases like what? Point vs interval? Multiple non-primitive "types" encoded as strings? 2. "Unacceptable" by whom/what? The DBMS? The relational model? Your programming standards? PS What  is your reason for not using [1.00874,1.00874]?

Comment: Are you sure you want a `range`? In the given case, wouldn't you have an unknown-size set of discrete values?

Comment: @philipxy Thank you for your questions. I tried to expand on them in Edit1

Comment: @Magoo I do not want a range because the design should work with different DBMS. I want to store data that can be given in different types. Please look at Edit 1

Comment: Re "three subtypes cannot be stored in one field" Please see the middle part of my answer. First you are imagining some "types" that you consider different, then you are saying that you can't have them in one column because a column has only one type. Well then just imagine the (super)"type" that is the set of all those values. Either way you have to *encode* your types' or type's values as subrows of values available in your DBMS, because the individual (sub)"types" are not all DBMS primitive types.

Comment: You seem to be mixing atomic weights with isotope weight (mass). Atomic weights are weighted averages of isotope weights given a distribution. Re "subtypes" You don't seem to storing values of subtypes, you seem to be recording *three different kinds of (incommensurate) information* that is "*about* atomic weight". But that still suggests three different tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> either as a numeric value or as a numeric interval

In the case of intervals you can store a single value *`x`* as `[`*`x`*`,`*`x`*`]`.

In this application it's not like the single values are *exact* values. They only represent a measurement to a certain accuracy. Even the interval endpoints only represent measurements to a certain accuracy.

> This table is unacceptable because the field Atomic_Weight contains values of different types.

The relational model doesn't care what values are in a "type". If no DBMS "type" fits yours then you must encode your ideal table & column into one or more table(s) and/or column(s).

You can encode them as strings. But then the DBMS doesn't know how to optimize queries involving their constituent values as well as for a multiple column encoding. And you must constantly decode and encode them to manipulate per parts.

```
Weight_string (isotope, weight)
    // VALUES (1, '1.00874'), (2, '[6.938, 6.997]')
```

> What is the best practice in such cases?

The main pattern is to have a table for every non-primitive subtype, and to encode the values of a subtype as one or more columns. (If a subtype has a subtype in turn, repeat.)

```
Weight_single (isotope, weight_single)
    // VALUES (1, 1.00874)
Weight_interval(isotope, weight_min, weight_max)
    // VALUES (2, 6.938, 6.997)
```

Another pattern is to encode each value in as many columns as necessary, whether they are used or not.

```
Weight_1_row_NULL_unused(isotope, single, interval_min, interval_max,
    // VALUES (1, 1.00874, NULL, NULL), (2, NULL, 6.938, 6.997)

Weight_1_row_type_tag(isotope, type_tag, if_single, if_finite_min, if_finite_max)
    // VALUES (1, 'single', 1.00874, 0, 0),(2, 'interval', 0, 6.938, 6.997)
```

Search re SQL subtypes/subtyping tables.

Comment: I think the pattern with a table for every subtype can solve my problem. But how do I make a query to get an atomic weight for a given isotope? By searching in weight_single and then weight_interval?

Comment: What format do you expect the result to be in? "An" atomic weight is sometimes a single value and sometimes an interval. Isotope number is essentially a surrogate for weight. Just carry around isotope numbers until you actually need to *do* something their weights; that will be a single-weight thing for ones that match Weight_single and an interval-weight thing for those that match Weight_interval. I suggest you try an example.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a table with three columns:

```
Isotope_ID, 
Atomic_Weight_From, 
Atomic_Weight_To.
```

In the case there is only one value, the `Atomic_Weight_From`, and `Atomic_Weight_To` will contain the same value.
This way you keep your table as clean as possible, as well as the code that needs to deal with it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't work well for my case. Sorry, I was not very clear in stating my question. Please look at Edit 1